# Error with Maven Dependencies when building HoloEverywhere

Tags: android, android-layout, maven, android-library

I'm trying to use [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)  in an Android application but I cannot get it to work properly. Whenever I try to import the library I get some errors. After Googling I've been able to remove error up to this one:

> The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library
>   'C:\Users\myself\.m2\repository\com\google\android\support-v4\r12\support-v4-r12.jar'

I have this library in the folder *"HoloEverywhere-master\support-library"* because it is included with HoloEverywhere. I am not at all familiar with Maven so I'm not too sure what exactly it is trying to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

check this dependency in pom.xml , you can link it as dependency with system scope :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
  <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
  <version>r12</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/external/something.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

then just correct system path. This is just quick fix. A bit better solution is to install that jar library into your local repository with this command :

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

OR

look for maven repository which contains given library e.g. :
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android/support-v4/r6 (be carefull this is r6 version and you propably need r12)

```
<repositories>
<repository>
  <id>my-alternate-repository</id>
  <url>http://myrepo.net/repo</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: Your comment shown me where to see those dependencies (pom.xml) so I thought it would be even easier just to delete this dependency. As I said in another comment I already have the android-support-v4-r12.jar file in the \lib folder. So I commented every references to support-v4 from all pom.xml files but I still get the error. Even after cleaning/rebuilding the project.

Comment: Another strange thing is that from "Project properties" -> "Java classpath" -> "Maven dependencies" I can still see support-v4 there even after deleting it from the pom.xml files. I tried cleaning/rebuilding, restarting Eclipse. Are these pom.xml files only read when importing the project?

Answer (score 0):

Is this really a Maven problem?

Have you tried Right-clicking on your project.

Selecting `Android Tools > Add Support Libraries...`

Comment: I can't remember if I did it myself or if it was like that when I imported the project into my workspace but I can definitely see the android-support-v4-r12.jar file in the \lib folder of the HoloEverywhere project.